# How to activate an Anaconda environment

Tags: python, virtualenv, anaconda, conda

I'm on Windows 8, using Anaconda 1.7.5 64bit.

I created a new Anaconda environment with

`conda create -p ./test python=2.7 pip`

from `C:\Pr\TEMP\venv\`.

This worked well (there is a folder with a new python distribution). conda tells me to type

`activate C:\PR\TEMP\venv\test`

to activate the environment, however this returns:

`No environment named "C:\PR\temp\venv\test" exists in C:\PR\Anaconda\envs`

How can I activate the environment? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Ran into this today. Looks very much likes a bug, reported as [conda-env#59](https://github.com/conda/conda-env/issues/59)

Answer (score 208, accepted):

If this happens you would need to set the PATH for your environment (so that it gets the right Python from the environment and Scripts\ on Windows).

Imagine you have created an environment called py33 by using:

```
conda create -n py33 python=3.3 anaconda
```

Here the folders are created by default in Anaconda\envs, so you need to set the PATH as:

```
set PATH=C:\Anaconda\envs\py33\Scripts;C:\Anaconda\envs\py33;%PATH%
```

Now it should work in the command window:

```
activate py33
```

The line above is the Windows equivalent to the code that normally appears in the tutorials for Mac and Linux:

```
$ source activate py33
```

More info:
https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!topic/anaconda/8T8i11gO39U

[Does `anaconda` create a separate PYTHONPATH variable for each new environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17386880/does-anaconda-create-a-separate-pythonpath-variable-for-each-new-environment)

Comment: I don't understand what the point of `activate` is if it doesn't set the path variable for me.

Comment: It's a bug. I sent [a fix](https://github.com/conda/conda-env/pull/60), hopefully the next version works correctly.

Comment: on Windows, use the `activate` command in the `cmd` prompt terminal

Comment: `export PATH="/$HOME/anaconda/bin:$PATH"` will work for MAC OS X users. That's what I did to get my virtualenvs to work.

Comment: I used powershell and the above method does not work. On cmd however it works fine.

Comment: What does adding "anaconda" at the end of "conda create -n py33 python=3.3 anaconda" do?

Answer (score 149):

**Use cmd instead of Powershell!**
I spent 2 hours before I switched to cmd and then it worked!

**create Environment:**

```
conda create -n your_environment_name
```

**see list of conda environments:**

```
conda env list
```

**activate your environment:**

```
conda activate your_environment_name
```

That's all folks

Comment: what if you want to use PowerShell?

Comment: Switching from Powershell to cmd did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: @SteveScott you need to run `conda init powershell` as explained [in this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65160772/1369188). I also run `conda config --set auto_activate_base false`

Answer (score 21):

All the former answers seem to be outdated.

`conda activate` was introduced in `conda` 4.4 and 4.6.

> `conda activate`: The logic and mechanisms underlying environment activation have been reworked. With conda 4.4, `conda activate` and `conda deactivate` are now the preferred commands for activating and deactivating environments. You’ll find they are much more snappy than the `source activate` and `source deactivate` commands from previous conda versions. The `conda activate` command also has advantages of (1) being **universal across all OSes**, shells, and platforms, and (2) not having path collisions with scripts from other packages like python virtualenv’s activate script.

Examples

```sh
conda create -n venv-name python=3.6
conda activate -n venv-name
conda deactivate
```

These new sub-commands are available in "Aanconda Prompt" and "Anaconda Powershell Prompt" automatically. To use `conda activate` in **every shell** (normal `cmd.exe` and powershell), check [expose `conda` command in every shell on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58211115/5101148).

References

- [How to Get Ready for the Release of conda 4.4](https://www.anaconda.com/how-to-get-ready-for-the-release-of-conda-4-4/)
- [Conda 4.6 Release](https://www.anaconda.com/conda-4-6-release/)

Comment: you don't need `-n` for activate. Just `conda activate base` is good enough.

Comment: Noobie question => Is "venv-name" hard coded here or does it actually represent a path to a venv for a given project?   Sounds like the simple answer is from Shital and should be "conda activate base"?

Comment: @Jamie `venv-name` represents a specific virtual environment name. `base` is the default virtual environment name where `conda` (conda is a command written in Python) is installed. My another answer may shed some light about this. https://stackoverflow.com/a/58112484/5101148

Comment: Oddly, as the venv-name is not base but (in my case 'pyspark3', One of the bigger issues I'm facing is that as the environment variables are adjusted to fit a scenario,, they machine requires a reboot before the registry can resolve the change.   It would be nice if the Environment variable could be tied to the venv name.

Answer (score 20):

Note that the command for activating an environment has changed in Conda version 4.4. The recommended way of activating an environment is now `conda activate myenv` instead of `source activate myenv`. To enable the new syntax, you should modify your  `.bashrc` file. The line that currently reads something like

```
export PATH="<path_to_your_conda_install>/bin:$PATH"
```

Should be changed to

```
. <path_to_your_conda_install>/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
```

This only adds the `conda` command to the path, but does not yet activate the `base` environment (which was previously called `root`). To do also that, add another line

```
conda activate base
```

after the first command. See all the details in [Anaconda's blog post](https://www.anaconda.com/blog/developer-blog/how-to-get-ready-for-the-release-of-conda-4-4/) from December 2017. (I think that this page is currently missing a newline between the two lines, it says `.../conda.shconda activate base`).

(This answer is valid for Linux, but it might be relevant for Windows and Mac as well)

Answer (score 9):

As you can see from the error message the paths, that you specified, are wrong. Try it like this:

```
activate ..\..\temp\venv\test
```

However, when I needed to install Anaconda, I downloaded it from [here](http://continuum.io/downloads) and installed it to the default paths (`C:\Anaconda`), than I put this path to the environment variables, so now Anacondas interpreter is used as default. If you are using PyCharm, for example, you can specify the interpreter there directly.

Comment: I'm am specifying the path where the anaconda environment is installed. I copied the ` activate ...` directly from the `conda create` output and tried running it from `C:/` as well as from `C:/pr/temp/venv`. Still it doesn't work...

Answer (score 8):

I've tried to activate env from Jenkins job (in bash) with
`conda activate base`  and it failed, so after many tries, this one worked for me (CentOS 7) :

```
source /opt/anaconda2/bin/activate base
```

Answer (score 5):

Below is how it worked for me

1. C:\Windows\system32>set CONDA_ENVS_PATH=d:\your\location
2. C:\Windows\system32>conda info

Shows new environment path

3. C:\Windows\system32>conda create -n YourNewEnvironment --clone=root

Clones default root environment

4. C:\Windows\system32>activate YourNewEnvironment

Deactivating environment "d:\YourDefaultAnaconda3"...
Activating environment "d:\your\location\YourNewEnvironment"...

5. [YourNewEnvironment] C:\Windows\system32>conda info -e

conda environments:
#

YourNewEnvironment
*  d:\your\location\YourNewEnvironment

root                     d:\YourDefaultAnaconda3

Answer (score 4):

Though @Simba had a good answer at the time, a lot has changed in the conda env since 4.6. `Conda activate (env-name)` overthrew `source activate (env-name)` for good but not without it own challenges. `conda activate` oftentimes forces your environment to base and makes you see something like this:

[image: (base)]

and throwing loads of error back at you. This can also be because `auto_activate_base` is set to True.

You can check this by using the following command

```sh
conda config --set auto_activate_base False
source ~/.bashrc
```

And to reactivate use this

```sh
conda config --set auto_activate_base True
source ~/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 3):

let's assume your environment name is **'demo'** and you are using anaconda and want to create a virtual environment:

(if you want python3)

```
    conda create -n demo python=3
```

(if you want python2)

```
    conda create -n demo python=2
```

After running above command you have to activate the environment by bellow command:

```
    source activate demo
```

Comment: source activate demo or conda activate demo?

Answer (score 3):

For me, using Anaconda Prompt instead of cmd or PowerShell is the key.

In Anaconda Prompt, all I need to do is `activate XXX`

Comment: This is the one that worked for me. After I did 'activate base', (base) appeared at the top of my bash shell.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same, a fix seems to have been made in the [source](https://github.com/conda/conda/blob/master/bin/activate.bat).

Comment: Hi @Nelson, note that, the link you supplied is now down. maybe put the instructions that were contained in that link in your answer instead ?

Answer (score 0):

One special case: **If you are trying to put the activation command in a unix script**, you might run into a problem because when you run the bash script, a new (linux) shell environment is created, and then destroyed when you exit that script. Think of this as running `bash`, then `source activate...` / `conda activate...`, then running `exit` to exit that shell... The result is you end up without an activated shell... More details in [How to execute script in the current shell on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14744904/how-to-execute-script-in-the-current-shell-on-linux):

**TL;DR**: for linux, to activate in a bash script and leave active:

1. Add the line `#!/bin/bash` as the **first line** of the script (This is anyways always a good practice, it specifies this is a bash script)
2. Type the command `source shell_script.sh` or `. shell_script.sh`

Note: `.` in bash is equivalent to `source` in bash.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using conda with Windows 10.
Anaconda was installed in:

```
C:\User\Admin\Anaconda3
```

After installation I've added this folders to system PATH:

```
C:\User\Admin\Anaconda3
C:\User\Admin\Anaconda3\Scripts
```

Then I ran "Anaconda promt" from windows start menu. From this anaconda promt I created my environment with

```
conda create --name my_env
```

And after that, I'm able to activate my conda environment **from regular CMD** by just typing:

```
activate my_env
```

Answer (score 0):

For me running this works in VS Code:

```
C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/Scripts/activate
```

Or just creating a new Terminal.

Answer (score -1):

Window:
**conda activate environment_name**

Mac: **conda activate environment_name**