# 'Activate Command not found'

Tags: python, virtualenv, arcgis, esri

I attempted the [following procedures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20081338/how-to-activate-an-anaconda-environment) to setup a conda environment for arcgis. The environment set-up correctly and I was prompted to activate the environment by typing "activate esri101" to which I was prompted...

```
$ activate esri101
sh.exe": activate: command not found
```

I'm a 3 out of 10 on the newbie to expert scale. I've tried setting my path as specified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20081338/how-to-activate-an-anaconda-environment) to no avail. I don't know where exactly to go from here.

EDIT: I retried it again today and it seemed to work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On a Linux/MacOSX environment, you must type (Documentation [here](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/intro.html))

```
$ source activate esri101
```

that is the Linux/MacOSX equivalent to the

```
activate esri101
```

that you would use on Windows

Comment: a reminder: windows means in `cmd` only, not `mingw`

Answer (score 3):

On my mac terminal, I had to use:

`conda activate env_name`