# activating environement in anaconda python 2.7

Tags: python, directory, virtualenv, anaconda

I'm using anaconda for managing python packages and don't seem to able to activate an environment that is located in a custom folder even though anaconda is perfectly aware of the folder and the environments' existence.

using "conda info --envs" in windows command prompt does show the env and its location but using 
"activate envname" returns

"No environment named 'envname' exists in C:\PGM\Anaconda\envs"

with C:\PGM\Anaconda being the root installation of anaconda (company policy, can't change that).

How do I point to this other location for env activation? 
I already tried:

adding the location to the windows PATH variable (permanently).
Temporarily adding the location to the windows PATH vars (in cmd).
And adding it in front of the envname like so: "activate C:\Users...\envname" but it returns the same message.

I looked into this post: [How to activate an Anaconda environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20081338/how-to-activate-an-anaconda-environment)

but its not working for me. My conda installation actually shows 3 envs directories when I issue the command "conda info" so it knows the directory as a envs candidate but it looks in just one for some reason even though it does find it when issuing "conda info --envs".

thanks in advance

Comment: Does it work to pass the full path of the environment to activate, like `activate C:\path\to\environment`?

Comment: No it doesn't, it interprets the path as the name of the env I want to activate. Strange cause it should work like this, I remember using it that way also in the past.

Comment: I have Anaconda installed and I created 2 additional environments. When I issue the command `conda info`, only one envs directory shows:  ...\Continuum\Anaconda2\envs. Does yours really show 3 envs directories?

Comment: When I navigate to the ...\Anaconda2\envs directory, it shows 2 subdirectories which are the names of my additional environments. My understanding is that conda creates all new environments in the \envs subdirectory of your root environment which for me is Anaconda2. There should not be more that one \envs directory, and that one directory contains a subdirectory for each environment.