# jupyter notebook select python

Tags: python, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

I have anaconda2 and anaconda3 installed on windows machine, have no access to internet and administrator rights. How can I switch between python 2 and 3 when starting jupyter? Basic "jupyter notebook" command starts python 2. With internet I would just add environment for python 3 and select it in jupyter notebook after start but how can I do this in this situation?

Comment: To switch between anaconda 2 and 3. Follow this link http://conda.pydata.org/docs/py2or3.html.

Comment: I red it. It requires internet connection and I haven't got it.

Comment: To switch from python 2 to python 3, type "activate python3" in terminal. Then pip install Jupyter. Then type ipython notebook.

Comment: could not find environment: python3

Comment: Follow this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20081338/how-to-activate-an-anaconda-environment

Comment: I have not got internet access!

Comment: You need to install a kernelspec for whichever version of Python you're not launching the notebook in. See the instructions here: http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install/kernel_install.html . If you already have ipykernel in both versions, you can do this with no internet connection.

Comment: The comment above from @ThomasK sorted it for me - I had previously installed 3.5.2 and then upgraded to 3.6, but could not get `jupyter notebook` to load the latter kernel. `python -m ipykernel install --user` resolved this.

Answer (score 1):

There's important points to consider:

- you have to have `jupyter notebook` installed in each environment you want to run it from
- if jupyter is only installed in one environment, your notebook will default to that environment no matter from which environment your start it, and you will have no option to change the notebook kernel (i.e. the conda package, and therefore which python version to use for your notebook)

You can list the packages in your environment with `conda list`. You can also check what environments exist with `conda info --envs` to make sure there's indeed one with python 3 (and use `conda list` to check it has jupyter installed).

From what you write, since your notebook defaults to python2, `conda list` should show you python 2 related packages.
So, as has been pointed, first activate the anaconda environment for python3 with the command `activate your_python3_environment` then restart your Notebook.
You don't need internet for this but you do need to be able to swap between anaconda2 and 3 (which you say are both installed) and both should have jupyter installed.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install python by Anaconda?

Try to install under Anaconda2/envs when choosing destination folder,

like this: 
D:/Anaconda2/envs/py3

then"activate py3" by cmd, py3 must be then same name of installation folder