# How do you activate an Anaconda environment in the Terminal with Mac OS X?

Tags: python, macos, anaconda

So I'm taking an online class and here are the instructions:

> Install Anaconda:
>
> Follow the instructions on the Anaconda download site.
>
> Create a conda environment called tensorflow:
>
> ```
> # Python 2.7
> $ conda create -n tensorflow python=2.7
>
> # Python 3.4
> $ conda create -n tensorflow python=3.4
>
> # Python 3.5
> $ conda create -n tensorflow python=3.5
> ```
>
> Activate the environment and use conda or pip to install TensorFlow inside it.

So how do you activate the environment?

I have Mac OS X by the way.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20081338/how-to-activate-an-anaconda-environment

Comment: Since you changed the accepted answer, may I ask if the current marked one works properly for you? Or does it display an error `Error: activate must be sourced. Run 'source activate envname'`

Comment: Yes the current one works properly for me @techraf

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> So how do you activate the environment?
>
> I have Mac OS X by the way.

On OS X, after creating the `tensorflow` environment using one of the commands from your example, execute:

```
source activate tensorflow
```

Answer (score 3):

to activate an environment with OSX, you enter `source activate` and then the environment name. for example

```
source activate tensorflow
```

then when you type `python`, it will start that version of python.

Your question implies you named all your environments `tensorflow`. You probably want to give them different names which indicate which version of python.

Then type `source deactivate` to deactivate the current environment.