# Conda command is not recognized on Windows 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-10, anaconda, conda

I installed Anaconda 4.4.0 (Python 3.6 version) on Windows 10 by following the instructions here: https://www.continuum.io/downloads. However, when I open the Command prompt window and try to write

```
conda list
```

I get the

> 'conda' command is not recognized...

error.

I tried to run

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Users\Alex\Anaconda3
```

but it didn't help. I also read that I might need to edit my `.bashrc` file, but I don't know how to access this file, and how I should edit it.

Comment: In Windows 10, set path using [Environmental variable](https://superuser.com/questions/949560/how-do-i-set-system-environment-variables-in-windows-10)

Comment: @ramesh, thanks for your comment. In the link that you game, the following comment appears: "
This method is only applicable to accounts from Administrators group. It is not possible to change environment variables of a regular User level account using this method". Unfortunately I am not in the Administrators group, so I cannot use this method. Is there some other way to do that? Thanks!

Comment: Names of some programs seem to have changed in Anaconda 5.1. I was trying to set up Jupyter as an Anaconda novice and found that the instructions for 5.0 didn't work for 5.1. Rolled back to 5.0 and got things to work. Specifically, I couldn't locate conda and "jupyter notebook" seems to have changed to "jupyter-notebook." Not sure what else may have changed.

Comment: In Windows 10, I simply ran the following: `PATH=%PATH%;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts`

Comment: If you installed anaconda jsut for your user, in windows 10 anaconda is in C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3. I added both the root path and the root/Scripts/ folder to the PATH, works fine.

Comment: The Anaconda installer recommends against adding Anaconda to your path. When I did I couldn't get `conda` to work due to openssl not being found. Instead they recommend using Anaconda Prompt (see answer below).

Answer (score 301, accepted):

In Windows, you will have to set the path to the location where you installed Anaconda3 to.

For me, I installed anaconda3 into `C:\Anaconda3`. Therefore you need to add `C:\Anaconda3` as well as `C:\Anaconda3\Scripts\` to your path variable, e.g. `set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Anaconda3;C:\Anaconda3\Scripts\`.

You can do this via powershell (see above, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776899(v=vs.85).aspx ), or hit the `windows` key → enter `environment` → choose from `settings` → `edit environment variables for your account` → select `Path` variable → `Edit` → `New`.

To test it, open a new dos shell, and you should be able to use conda commands now. E.g., try `conda --version`.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I added C:\Users\Alex\Anaconda3 to the path in System variables, but conda command is still not recognized. I also wrote "C:\Users\Alex>set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Users\Alex\Anaconda3" in my command prompt window, but it didn't work either. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Sorry, did not notice there's also `C:\Anaconda3\Scripts\`in my Path ...  In the Scripts subfolder you should also manually find a `conda.exe` .

Comment: Thanks. What should I do after I find it? add it to the path as well?

Comment: Yup, add the folder to the path (sorry If I wasn't clear enough about that).

Comment: I installed Anaconda for all users on my Windows 10, so it ended up in path: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3.  I had to add the following in my path for conda to work: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts.

Comment: @mjoppich but if the conda.exe does not get install for some reason? I do not have a conda.exe in my scripts folder. What to do?

Comment: why does the latest installer say do NOT add conda to PATH?

Comment: Because you are supposed to work in environments. These kind of have their own $PATH variable.

Adding all the conda binaries to the global system may hide sytem binaries, etc. Nonetheless, advanced users may know what they are doing and still add it to their PATH.

Comment: Things have been changed after conda 4.6. See the answer by Simba below.

Comment: You might have to refresh the environment variables afterwards. run 'set PATH=C' , and then close and restart the command window

Comment: You also need C:\Anaconda3\Library\bin.

Comment: For PowerShell I actually had to do this:
$Env:PATH += ";C:\Users\bryanloz\Anaconda3\Scripts"

Comment: This did not work for me. Try the answer from Simba in this thread.

Answer (score 127):

Things have been **changed after conda 4.6**.

Programs "Anaconda Prompt" and "Anaconda Powershell" expose the command `conda` for you automatically. Find them in your startup menu.

If you don't wanna use the prompts above and try to make `conda` available in a standard `cmd.exe` or a standard Powershell. Read the following content.

---

#### Expose `conda` in Every Shell

The purpose of the following content is to make command `conda` available both in `cmd.exe` and Powershell on Windows.

If you have already checked "Add Anaconda to my PATH environment variable" during Anaconda installation, skip step 1.

[image: Anaconda installation options on Windows]

1. If Anaconda is installed for the current use only, add `%USERPROFILE%\Anaconda3\condabin` (I mean `condabin`, not `Scripts`) into the environment variable `PATH` (the user one). If Anaconda is installed for all users on your machine, add `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\condabin` into `PATH`.

   [How do I set system environment variables on Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/949560/how-do-i-set-system-environment-variables-in-windows-10)
2. Open a **new** Powershell, run the following command once to initialize `conda`.

   ```sh
   conda init
   ```

These steps make sure the `conda` command is exposed into your `cmd.exe` and Powershell.

---

#### Extended Reading: `conda init` from Conda 4.6

Caveat: Add the new `\path\to\anaconda3\condabin` but not `\path\to\anaconda3\Scripts` into your `PATH`. This is a big **change introduced in `conda` 4.6**.

[Activation script initialization fron `conda` 4.6 release log](https://www.anaconda.com/conda-4-6-release/)

> Conda 4.6 adds extensive initialization support so that more shells than ever before can use the new `conda activate` command. For more information, read the output from `conda init –help` We’re especially excited about this new way of working, because removing the need to modify `PATH` makes Conda much less disruptive to other software on your system.

In the old days, `\path\to\anaconda3\Scripts` is the one to be put into your `PATH`. It exposes command `conda` and the default Python from "base" environment at the same time.

After `conda` 4.6, `conda` related commands are **separated into `condabin`**. This makes it possible to **expose ONLY command `conda`** without activating the Python from "base" environment.

#### References

- [Conda 4.6 Release](https://www.anaconda.com/conda-4-6-release/)
- [How do I prevent Conda from activating the base environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57974390/5101148)

Comment: Thanks, by far the best answer. I didn't want to add Python and everything else to my path, I wanted to follow best practices and use Virtual Environments which all the other answers mess up.

Comment: This is the correct answer in 2020 and by far the cleanest way to handle conda environments & paths. Also note, if you use git-bash(mingw), msys(2), or cygwin you have to run `\path\to\anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe init bash` instead.

Comment: To revert this, I presume I can reset PATH and call `conda init` again?

Comment: Note that if you installed [Miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html) instead of Anaconda, you'll need to add `%USERPROFILE%\miniconda3\condabin` to your `PATH`.

Comment: Instead of "a new Powershell", I specifically had to run `conda init`in an "Anaconda Powershell Prompt".

Answer (score 25):

The newest version of the Anaconda installer for Windows will also install a windows launcher for "Anaconda Prompt" and "Anaconda Powershell Prompt". If you use one of those instead of the regular windows cmd shell, the `conda` command, python etc. should be available by default in this shell.

[image]

Answer (score 24):

When you install anaconda on windows now, it doesn't automatically add Python or Conda.

If you don’t know where your conda and/or python is, you type the following commands into your anaconda prompt

[image]

Next, you can add **Python and Conda** to your path by using the setx command in your command prompt.
[image]

Next close that command prompt and open a new one. Congrats you can now use conda and python

Source: https://medium.com/@GalarnykMichael/install-python-on-windows-anaconda-c63c7c3d1444

Comment: Hi, thanks. after install anaconda, "Close" the terminal (I use ubuntu bash in windows 10) and open a new one, which means restart the system in Ubuntu dose the trick!

Answer (score 16):

If you want to use Anaconda in regular cmd on windows you need to add several paths to your Path env variable.

Those paths are (**instead of Anaconda3 the folder may be Anaconda2 depending on the Anaconda version** on your PC):

```
\Users\YOUR_USER\Anaconda3
\Users\YOUR_USER\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin
\Users\YOUR_USER\Anaconda3\Library\usr\bin
\Users\YOUR_USER\Anaconda3\Library\bin
\Users\YOUR_USER\Anaconda3\Scripts
\Users\YOUR_USER\Anaconda3\bin
```

Answer (score 3):

I had also faced the same problem just an hour back. I was trying to install QuTip [Quantum Toolbox in Python](http://qutip.org/)
Unfortunately, I didn't stumble onto this page in time.
Say you have downloaded Anaconda installer and run it until the end.
Naively, I opened the command prompt in windows 10 and proceded to type the following commands as given in the [qutip installation docs](http://qutip.org/docs/4.1/installation.html).

> conda create -n qutip-env
>
> conda config --append channels conda-forge
>
> conda install qutip

But as soon as I typed the first line I got the following response

> conda is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

[error messsage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ja0lf.png)

I went ahead and tried some other things as seen in this figures
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYWGn.png)
Finally after going through a number conda websites, I understood how one fixes this problem.
Type Anaconda prompt in the search bar at the bottom like this (same place where you hail Cortana)
[Anaconda prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wB8kt.png)

Once you are here all the conda commands will work as usual

Answer (score 2):

Even I got the same problem when I've first installed Anaconda. It said `'conda' command not found`.

So I've just setup two values[added two new paths of Anaconda] system environment variables in the PATH variable which are: `C:\Users\mshas\Anaconda2\` & `C:\Users\mshas\Anaconda2\Scripts`

Lot of people forgot to add the second variable which is *"Scripts"* just add that then `conda` command works.

Comment: That's it ! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

If you have installed Visual studio 2017 (profressional)

The install location:

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts
```

If you do not want the hassle of putting this in your path environment variable on windows and restarting you can run it by simply:

```
C:\>"C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe" update qt pyqt
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the python.exe in C://.../Anaconda3 installation file as well as C://.../Anaconda3/Scripts to PATH.

First go to your installation directory, in my case it is installed in C://Users/user/Anaconda3 and shift+right click and press "Open command window here" or it might be "Open powershell here", if it is powershell, just write cmd and hit enter to run command window. Then run the following command setx PATH %cd%

Then go to C://Users/user/Anaconda3/Scripts and open the command window there as above, then run the same command "setx PATH %cd%"

Answer (score 1):

To prevent having further issues with SSL you should add all those to Path :

```
 SETX PATH "%PATH%;C:\<path>\Anaconda3;C:\<path>\Anaconda3\Scripts;C:\<path>\Anaconda3\Library\bin"
```

[Requests (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.") Error in PyCharm requesting website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54135206/requests-caused-by-sslerrorcant-connect-to-https-url-because-the-ssl-module/54211170)

Answer (score 0):

**case #1**
You should set 3 path:

```
%ANACONDAPATH%;
%ANACONDAPATH%\Scripts;
%ANACONDAPATH%\Library\bin;
```

It will solve problem:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>conda update conda
Solving environment: failed

CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch/repodata.json.bz2>
Elapsed: -
...
```

**case #2**
Also you can use Anaconda Promd (for Win10) instead CLI (cmd.exe)

Answer (score 0):

According to the official documentation, for Windows users there are two environment variable PATHs which can be updated, depending on how your Miniconda/Anaconda distribution has been installed -- one is the SYSTEM PATH, the other is the USER PATH: https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/master/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#activating-an-environment

Basically it says the following: If like the official recommendation you have installed `conda` for yourself on the user level only, you can add a path similar to `C:\Users\<user-name>\miniconda3\Scripts` to the user variables.

Please remember to change to `Anaconda` if you are not using `miniconda` and update the  to your system username in order for this to work.

However, if you have a system level install for all users on the same machine, you should add the path `c:\miniconda3\Scripts\` to the system variables.

Also, please run `conda init` in your PowerShell to have conda working on your PowerShell. If there is a Python version already installed on your PC, you can disable "app execution aliases" in Settings (under "Manage app execution aliases") for this to use only the Python ones on the command line to avoid conflict.

Answer (score 0):

I just installed Python 3.11 and then tried to install Anaconda 23.5.2 in Windows 10, but there were conflicts when I tried to run the version commands.

So I fully removed both and just installed Anaconda.  I opened a command prompt and python was showing up, but I had to add Anaconda to my environment variables as mjoppich explained both to Anaconda3 and also the scripts, as in:

> C:\Users\myName\anaconda3\

> C:\Users\myName\anaconda3\Scripts

Which worked.  What was odd was I had installed both python and then conda without issue a few weeks ago with a slightly older version and had a path to python AND the path to Anaconda in my windows environment variables PATH.

I'm posting as these are the correct steps with the newest version to date.

Answer (score 0):

Just run the following command to set any path in Environment Variables in Windows 10:

**This command will append the specified path to the PATH variable.**

**`PATH=%PATH%;C:\your\path;C:\your\path\to\a\directory`**

The above command will add two paths in the PATH variable.
that is: **`C:\your\path`** and **`C:\your\path\to\a\directory`**

Answer (score 0):

Find the Anaconda or Miniconda folders like:

```
C:\Users\username\Anaconda3
C:\Users\username\Ainiconda3\Scripts
```

or

```
C:\Users\username\miniconda3
C:\Users\username\miniconda3\Scripts
```

Copy and paste to Windows Environment Variables

```
Advanced System Settings -> Environment Variables -> User Variables for username -> Path
```

Edit the `Path` variable and add the above paths.

Restart the terminal/CMD.

```
conda init
conda activate base
```