# Python module not found even though "Requirement Already satisfied in Pip"

Tags: python, pip, python-requests

writing some python in OS X, and it's saying several packages I installed with pip "ImportError: no module named requests"

When running pip install requests

```
> sudo -H pip install requests 
Requirement already satisfied: requests in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages 
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from requests) 
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from requests) 
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.22,>=1.21.1 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from requests) 
Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.6,>=2.5 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from requests)
```

it's erroring on twindb_cloudflare, requests, group, tarutil, and MySQL DB. I'm able to run the exact same imports on another script (in the same folder) without error.

Comment: Are you executing those scripts using the same Python interpreter…?

Comment: yes. python file.py on both.

Answer (score 26):

In my case, I was running a python version included with Jupyter, which installs modules in a different place than the default one apparently. I found that out by running this in Jupyter:

```
import sys
sys.executable
```

which gave me

```
'/usr/local/Cellar/jupyterlab/3.0.13/libexec/bin/python3.9'
```

I was then able to run the following command in Jupyter:

```
!/usr/local/Cellar/jupyterlab/3.0.13/libexec/bin/python3.9 -m pip install scipy matplotlib
```

and then I was able to import my modules:

```
import scipy.stats
import matplotlib
```

Answer (score 24):

Run in command prompt.

```
pip list
```

Check what version you have installed on your system if you have an old version.

Try to uninstall the package...

```
pip uninstall requests
```

Try after to install it:

```
pip install requests
```

You can also test if pip does not do the job.

```
easy_install requests
```

Comment: is there an environment variable like `$PATH` but specifically for conda?

Comment: Hey @frank check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44597662/conda-command-is-not-recognized-on-windows-10

Comment: Thanks. Uninstalling and reinstalling worked for me

Comment: Thanks. 「easy_install requests」worked for me.

Answer (score 12):

i had the same issue(also in MAC OS) and solved it by instead running the python script with python3:
python3 script.py

in my case i was also using pip3 and not pip.

Answer (score 11):

I suffered from this problem and finally found the solution.

> Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable

> Requirement already satisfied: django in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (2.2.12)

use
'sudo' to crossoff user installation issue;

and pip install --target=/usr/local/python3.7/site-packages --upgrade {module_name}

someone mentioned this and worked for me.

Answer (score 11):

**Method 1**

If your system has more than one Python version installed, like in my ubuntu by default Python versions are `python` and `python3`, then pip also has different versions like `pip` and `pip3`. So in this situation access pip by specific Python version with `-m` like:

```
python3 -m pip install package_name
```

or

```
python -m pip install package_name
```

Make sure the use of `sudo` if you are on Linux.

**Method 2**

You need to find installation directory (from where Python finds modules). For this run the following Python script:

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

In my case it returns:

```
['', '/usr/lib/python38.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.8', '/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload', '/home/mudasir_habib/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
```

These are the paths that Python uses to find modules, I copy the *dist-packages* path. So now run the command by providing target path for installation like below:

```
python -m pip install package_name -t /your/copied/path
```

In my case I run the following command that solve my problem:

```
sudo python3 -m pip install keras -t /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
```

Comment: Can't we set the target path permanently or do we have to define everytime we install a package?

Comment: Normally pip manages all the things by itself.  But some times when we have installed multiple python and pip version installed, then pip confused to find correct path so we need to provide manually.

Comment: THIS!
```python3 -m pip install package_name

Comment: Specifying path with `-t` flag worked for me. Using conda environment where I was facing the problem to install packages with pip from ssh, this resolved my problem by specifying site-packages path as `~/anaconda3/envs/<ENV_NAME>/lib/python<PYTHON_VERSION>/site-packages` Thanks

Answer (score 7):

If you are using a Mac, it could be that you installed the modules with pip (meaning python2, but you execute your code with python3 which does not have the modules you installed for python2).

Mac has python version 2 set as default and usually does not come with pip preinstalled or is linked with version 2. I recommend leaving it that way. Use version 3 for your personal use cases and leave your Mac with version 2 as default. As you have to install python3 yourself, means you might also want to check/install pip3.

Check if you have python 3 installed:

```
python3 --version
```

Check if you have pip3 installed (usually included by default since python 3.4):

```
pip3 --version
```

Check what packages you have installed with pip3:

```
pip3 list
```

If you use an editor tool, make sure to set it to use python3 when running your file.

Example for VS Code:
Set VS Code to use Python3 on the bottom right corner, which you should see when having a .py file open: [image: Set Python version]

And now if you want to import any modules into python, make sure to install them with pip3:

```
pip3 install package_name
```

If you run into permission issue, you might consider to run the command with sudo rights:

```
sudo pip3 install package_name
```

Comment: You can take advantage of virtual envs capabilities and managing python versions becomes a lot easy https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv

Comment: Following the sudo pip3 advice is what fixed the problem for me.  Sudo was the key for my system.

Comment: There are a number of reasons why sudo pip is considered a bad practice, see for example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21055859/what-are-the-risks-of-running-sudo-pip/21056000#21056000

Answer (score 3):

On my Windows machine, more than one version of Python were installed in different locations.
Hence when I tried to install Pillow library as `pip install Pillow`, it was giving the message that "Requirement already satisfied and showing the path of another directory where another version of Python installed:

[image]

To solve this error, I used the `--target` switch with PIP command as below:

```
python -m pip install Pillow --target="c:\Program Files\Python310\Lib\site-packages"
```

And it worked successfully

Answer (score 2):

I am using Mac and I had also same issue. I solved it by upgrading pip then install the relevant package.

Firstly install the latest version of pip:

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip
```

Then install the package (for example, numpy):

```
pip3 install numpy
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to share my findings and perhaps a newbie error, but in my case mariadb was installed using 'sudo pip3 install mariadb' and I tried to run my script with 'python myscript.py' and that didn't work. But I worked when I use 'python3 myscript.py', seems to be that it matters which pyhton you use.

Answer (score 0):

My Raspberry Pi 4 did not recognise the `ipython` command and the following was displayed when attempting to install iPython:

```
me@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo pip3 install ipython
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Requirement already satisfied: ipython in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (5.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pexpect in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from ipython) (4.6.0)
```

I knew this wasn't a PATH issue as iPython is a pip package.

I found an `IPython` directory under `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/` and inside this directory I found program `__main__.py`.

Running `__main__.py` started iPython:

```
python3 /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/IPython/__main__.py
```

I added the following alias to my `.bashrc` file to allow me to simply type `ipython`.

```
alias ipython='python3 /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/IPython/__main__.py'
```

Comment: @Tomerikoo Thanks for changing "bashrc" to ".bashrc", but I don't know why you felt compelled to remove the last line of my answer? Let me add it here: "Hope the above is helpful. God bless"

Comment: Please see [Why are fellow users removing thank-you's from my questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/328379/6045800)

Answer (score 0):

If you have Python 2 installed then you can use the following command to install pip for Python 2:

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
python get-pip.py
```

Now you can check for pip2 and can try to run your program:

```
pip2 --version
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on Windows installing pyModbusTCP. The solution for me was similar to another here. I had to run PowerShell as admin, then "pip install pyModbusTCP" worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is relevant, but I was having a similar issue until I realized I was trying to `import request`, but the module name is `requests`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

**Here is one line solution that works like magic**

```
$(which python) -m pip install package_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's not the required solution you were looking for but in my case, I had a project in pycharm that requires PIP library so I ran the following command:

```
pip install Pillow
```

in the project terminal and it got me the library required for the project.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I've ran it in a virtual environment (venv) and it solved it for me

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, and it was caused by having python installed both from the Microsoft store and python's installer.
I fixed it by uninstalling the Microsoft store version in "Add or remove programs" tab in windows.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, but in my case, none of the answers above worked. The reason behind it is probably Windows 11.

[image]

Despite "listed" and "requirement already satisfied" the IDLE couldn't load the library at all.

I've repeated the installation process in the same manner for the other directory

```
\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0>pip install openpyxl
```

and it started working!

[image]

I believe the reasonable way could be the installation of a Python library both in the standard folder discussed widely on the web as well as in the directory shown here in the situation when you are a Windows 11 user.