# Django: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'

Tags: django, python-3.x

when i run server i have below error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
```

but requests have been installed on my system, when i run `sudo pip3 install requests` command, output is :

```
Requirement already satisfied: requests in /home/sadegh-khan/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
```

the terminal pic of my error and command to install requests is:
[image: ModuleNotFoundEr]

Comment: which command you are running to run server?

Comment: python manage.py runserver 8002

Comment: try running `python3 manage.py runserver 8002`

Comment: According to the following post: [Python module not found even though “Requirement Already satisfied in Pip”
](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45345642/5433307) easy-install solved my problem! `easy_install requests`
but why!?

Comment: python3 manage.py runserver 8002 would solved your problem because python manage.py runserver will run in python2 but you installed requests for python3 that is the problem

Comment: after easy-install i tried python3 manage.py, but problem solved. Of course now also i am using python manage.py and i have not any problem.

Answer (score 0):

You're installing requests by running pip as sudo, which means it is installed globally. Yet your screenshot (and please don't post screenshots anyway) shows you are inside a virtualenv, `.venv`.

Don't use `sudo`; just install requests inside the venv.

Comment: Are you running Django under Python 2 or 3? And are you sure you're in the same venv?

Comment: i am sure that running Django under Python 3. yes im sure in the same Virtualenv.

Answer (score 0):

**If you are using Python3** instead of running the server using **python manage.py runserver** go ahead and run **python3 manage.py runserver**

**Instead of**

```
python manage.py runserver
```

**or**

```
py  manage.py runserver
```

**Run**
python3  manage.py runserver