# Why does it say ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL' if I have it installed?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

when i run `pip install Pillow` or `pip install --upgrade Pillow` it says `Requirement already satisfied`. I have only 1 version of python(3.10.2) and the latest version of pip.When I run a program with `from PIL import`or anything similar it says `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'`.I also have pygame and PyAutoGUI installed, both work but pygame doesn't show up in `pip list`.Im on Windows 10. I tried uninstalling and installing Pillow and repairing Python  but it doesn't fix it.

Comment: Where are you running these commands - terminal or any IDE?

Based on the information you provided most likely scenario is you are running these commands from two different environments.

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45345377/python-module-not-found-even-though-requirement-already-satisfied-in-pip) might help

Comment: Im running it in the terminal.

Answer (score -2):

That's a small problem, just **update your Pillow package**.

```
pip install Pillow --upgrade
```

Pillow-4.2.1 was on my system, it upgraded to Pillow-5.1.0 and now everything works just fine.

Comment: Both upper and lower case should work fine: https://pypi.org/project/pillow/ https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/

Comment: well sorry is mistook the logic.

Comment: now it gonna work

Comment: I don't see how upgrading it would fix the fact that it can't be found. (Also, why are you running 5.1.0? Pillow's on 9.0.1 now.)

Comment: The first sentence of the question is *"when i run `pip install Pillow` or __`pip install --upgrade Pillow`__ it says Requirement already satisfied"*

Comment: he may have an other environment on any ide.