# Why cant I import/use installed libraries in Python

Tags: python, libraries

I recently downloaded Python 3.10 because I used 3.9. At first, everything worked fine. Sadly, I can't use installed libraries nor use newly downloaded ones, since I deleted Python 3.9. What can I do about this problem?

VSCode gives me this Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "e:\XXXX\XXXX.py", line 5, in <module>

    from playsound import playsound

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'playsound'
```

Comment: You may have installed the package with the wrong version of Python.  It's not unusual for a system to have multiple versions of Python installed.

Comment: Uninstall and install using command pip3 install playsound

Comment: And what can I do now to install the libraries to the right Python version?

Comment: `python3.10 -m pip install <package>`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70300436/12890258    try this

Answer (score 1):

You can check installed packages using this command:

```
pip freeze
```

or

```
pip list
```

Uninstall and install using command `pip install <package-name>`