# Turbodbc Installation error No module named 'pybind11' inspite of installing pybind11 successfully

Tags: python, ubuntu, turbodbc

Hi I am trying to install turbodbc in ubuntu for my project. I have my venv activated and already installed pybind11 first yet I receive this error "No Module found : pybind11". I have checked the package is being installed in my venv folder only ( you can see that in the logs attached below).

I have also tried FLAGS="-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0" pip install turbodbc along with pip install turbodbc as I found that as a solution in one of github links.

I have also tried to import pybind11 on a python program and it does that successfully.
Can you please help me resolve this or show some other method to install turbodbc?

here's my error logs :

```
pip install pybind11
Requirement already satisfied: pybind11 in /mnt/c/Users/doshi/Arthsarita_venv/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages (2.11.1)
(venv) anuj@Suzalin15:/mnt/c/Users/doshi/Arthsarita$ CFLAGS="-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0" pip install turbodbc
Collecting turbodbc
  Using cached turbodbc-4.8.0.tar.gz (83 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [21 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/mnt/c/Users/doshi/Arthsarita_venv/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "/mnt/c/Users/doshi/Arthsarita_venv/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/mnt/c/Users/doshi/Arthsarita_venv/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-xg8tqa7_/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 355, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-xg8tqa7_/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 325, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-xg8tqa7_/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 507, in run_setup
          super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend, self).run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-xg8tqa7_/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 341, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 78, in <module>
        File "<string>", line 71, in str
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pybind11'
      [end of output]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70300436/8609909 Check this answer and see if it solves your problem