# Python - installing package using setuptools (setup.py) on AzureML

Tags: python, package, environment, azure-machine-learning-service

I'm currently working on a project where I try to implement DINO:DETR (https://github.com/IDEA-Research/DINO) on AzureML to train a model with it. I've succesfully created an environment with CUDA 11.3 and torch 1.12.0 and this environment is succesfully compiled. Step 4 of the installation guide is installing the package using a setup.py file (to install MultiScaleDeformableAttention):

```
python setup.py build install
```

**First question:** Is it possible to install this setup.py in the environment (stc-cuda-env) directly?

The method I used now if using subprocess in the main.py file to install this setup.py directly to the compute.

```
subprocess.run(["python", "setup.py", "build", "install"])
```

I can find the following information in my logfile, which indicates that the installation was succesfull:

`Installed /opt/conda/envs/ptca/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MultiScaleDeformableAttention-1.0-py3.8-linux-x86_64.egg`
`Processing dependencies for MultiScaleDeformableAttention==1.0`
`Finished processing dependencies for MultiScaleDeformableAttention==1.0`

When MultiScaleDeformableAttention is imported (either manually or in the code function build_model_main()) I get the following error: **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MultiScaleDeformableAttention'**

**Second question:** How can I succesfully import/install the package on AzureML?

BTW: I checked whether GPU is available using and the output is **True**

```
print(torch.cuda.is_available())
```

Answer (score 0):

For the module issue, you should be able to install the specific version of the module directly since setup.py is already recognized:

```
pip3 install multiscaledeformableattention==1.0
```

As for directly installing it, the only way I found is described in [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-python-worker/issues/588), but it relies on deploying an entire custom image using docker which is not ideal.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I just tried this and logging everything gives this result: Requirement already satisfied: multiscaledeformableattention==1.0 in /opt/conda/envs/ptca/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MultiScaleDeformableAttention-1.0-py3.8-linux-x86_64.egg (1.0) but I still get this error: 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MultiScaleDeformableAttention'

Comment: Considering this seems to be the same python version, I have no clue. But I did find some soultions to a similar problem here:

 [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45345377/python-module-not-found-even-though-requirement-already-satisfied-in-pip)

Comment: i found out (using google colab) that I have to restart my kernel in order to import the module (which makes sense). The problem with computes on AzureML is that you cannot restart them, since you will lose the package. Do you have any other ideas?