# how to install package for python3 using pip? Now it always install for python2

Tags: python, pip

I've been puzzled for a while. I can't install/upgrade any package for my python35 now.
I have python27 and python35(via anaconda) on mac.
Whenever I want to install a python package via pip, the one paired with python2 was invoked.

Go to anaconda folder(where my python35 installed):
ls -al | grep pip
I got the result:

```
-rwxrwxr-x    1 xx  staff      113 Jul 26  2016 conda-pipbuild
-rwxr-xr-x    1 xx  staff      230 Dec 17 21:40 pip
-rwxr-xr-x    1 xx  staff      230 Dec 17 21:40 pip3
-rwxr-xr-x    1 xx  staff      230 Dec 17 21:40 pip3.5
```

In my .bashrc file, I defined:

```
 alias python2=/usr/bin/python2.7
 alias python=~/anaconda/bin/python3.5
```

When I type python2:

```
$ python2
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 23 2015, 19:19:21) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.59.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

When I type python:

```
   $ python
    Python 3.5.2 |Anaconda custom (x86_64)| (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:52:12) 
    [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 4.2 (clang-425.0.28)] on darwin
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

When type: pip -V

```
pip 9.0.1 from /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg (python 2.7)
```

When type pip3 -V

```
-bash: pip3: command not found
```

which pip

```
/usr/local/bin/pip
```

To reinstall pip3, I downloaded get-pip.py from https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing/
From the doc it says, it will install the correct pip according to the version of Python runs the script.
Therefore, I ran

```
python get-pip.py 
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /Users/xxx/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages
```

Below shows When I try to install a package with pip:

```
pip install tushare --upgrade
Collecting tushare
  Using cached tushare-1.0.7-py2-none-any.whl
Requirement already up-to-date: lxml>=3.8.0 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from tushare)
```

Comment: Depending on how you installed python3 you may find that you actually have a `pip3.5` or something similar. If you want to access it when typing `pip3`, you should set an alias for it. Better yet, package your code into virtual environments and when you're inside a venv you will be able to access pip3 with `pip`

Comment: what path should I put for the pip3 alias? I guess I have is somewhere here:/Users/xxx/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages      according to get-pip.py  @CharlesAddis

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install pip with Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6587507/how-to-install-pip-with-python-3)

Comment: @Lisa you can put the alias wherever you want, but typically that would go in /usr/local/bin if this is a python version you installed yourself otherwise it would go in /usr/bin if it is the system installed version of python. Other places you could put it are `~/bin` if you have a bin directory in your homedir. It all depends on your PATH

Comment: @Gahan that's a mac.

Comment: You probably have several pip scripts in different folders on your system and either PATH selects one of them or /usr/bin/pip symlinks to one of them. Try finding all executable files called pip\* on the system.

Comment: I saw this post, it cannot solve my problem@PaulRooney

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `pip` that comes with Anaconda does not get its symbolic link for `pip3` by default. You can check which `pip` you are using by

```
which pip
```

Likely, it is not the pip from your Anaconda 3 installation.
The way to fix it is pretty simple: Create the symbolic link yourself. Since Anaconda3's binary folder is already in your path (you can check it by `which python` or `which python3`), you can go to the `anaconda3/bin` folder

```
ls -al | grep pip
```

You may be able to see something like this

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 youraccount youraccount     120 Jul 13 21:58 pip
```

Then create a symbolic link that points to it

```
ls -s pip pip3
```

That's it. You can try `which pip3` again to see if that is the pip you want to refer to.

### EDIT

I notice that you are using `alias` to access the python of Anaconda. As there are a lot of useful tools under `anaconda/bin`, it is necessary to put the entire folder into your path. At the same time, it is better to remove the `alias` in case of anything weird happening in the future.

To add `anaconda/bin` to your path, first you need to check what your `PATH` variable in bash looks like

```
echo $PATH
```

I guess you don't have `anaconda/bin` anywhere in the printout. Otherwise, you should be able to use pip3 without an issue.

If you use all default choices of anaconda, you should have this line in your `.bashrc` or `.profile` or `.bash_profile`

```
export PATH="/Users/youraccount/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
```

If you already have this, run `source .bashrc` (or the file that contains the line), you should be able to see `anaconda/bin` in your `PATH`.

If not, put the line there, and source the file or restart the terminal. Also, remove the alias for python3.

Last, start this answer post from top to create the symbolic link for `pip` with the name you want (say, `pip3`)

This should solve your problem.

Comment: I have 4 different verion when type: ls -al | grep pip, how should I proceed?@Yo Hsiao
-rwxrwxr-x    1 xx  staff      113 Jul 26  2016 conda-pipbuild
-rwxr-xr-x    1 xx  staff      230 Dec 17 21:40 pip
-rwxr-xr-x    1 x  staff      230 Dec 17 21:40 pip3
-rwxr-xr-x    1 x  staff      230 Dec 17 21:40 pip3.5

Comment: @lisa If you read the `pip`, `pip3`, `pip3.5` in plain text, you will see they are all identical. My version does not come with `pip3` nor `pip3.5`. In this case, you don't need to create a symbolic link. You just need to put the whole folder in your `PATH`.

Answer (score 5):

PIP is also a python package. You can use,

```
python3 -m pip install foo
```

Comment: When I use sudo python3 -m pip install foo, it still uses python2. However, when I use python3 -m pip install foo, it works (using python3). How is this possible?

Comment: run `sudo python3` and `python3` in the terminal and see what it gives you.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I finally solved my own issue. But it doesn't make sense to me. Anyone could help to explain why it solved the problem?

1. I tried solutions posted here(doesn't help or I didn't understand)
2. I decided to use conda to install the package, since my python3 was installed with Anaconda, and my python2 was installed seperately.
3. I found my terminal cannot understand "conda"
4. I typed "export PATH=~/anaconda/bin:$PATH", according to [conda command is not recognized on windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44597662/conda-command-is-not-recognized-on-windows-10)
5. suddenly, pip install conrrectly installs package to python3. Type pip -V gives me pip3.

Comment: Prakash Palnati

Comment: @Yo Hsiao would you pls help me understand why above solution worked?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, Install pip3 :

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt install python3-pip
```

now check the version of pip3 :

```
pip3 -V
```

Install package using pip3 for python3 :

```
sudo  pip3 install django
```

Much python packages require also the dev package, so install it too:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev
```

You can also create virtual environment for python3 and install package for pyhton3 using pip :

```
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3 envs
source envs/bin/activate
pip install package-name
```

Refer [here](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html) for more on conda environments.

Comment: In my experience, this may be tricky as the pip3 installed through apt-get may not be in the `anaconda3` folder. If you already have python3 on your system, this pip3 will go with it. Once using it to install packages, the packages will be part of the original python3 in the system as opposed to the Anaconda. Correct me if I am mistaken.

Comment: @YoHsiao, you are right at your point.
We can also create virtual environment for python3 and install package for python3.

Comment: Was apt-get ported to Mac OS while I was sleeping?

Comment: @n.m. If you want the equivalent to apt-get or yum on Mac OS X You can use `brew install PACKAGE_NAME` to install the package available.

Answer (score 0):

### Description

In most cases, python2 doesnt come with **pip** installed. I am using macOS and I used these commands to run:

### Solution

```sh
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/get-pip.py --output get-pip.py
sudo python2 get-pip.py
```

Then use:

```sh
pip2 install <package_name> 
#or 
python2 -m pip install <package_name>
```

### Hint:

From a personal experience, I suggest not alias your python version in the `.bashrc` or `.zshrc`. It will affect other installations or set up by your system (for example if you use vim). Instead, specify the version of python when you run your code with

```sh
python2 <file_name>
# or 
python3 <file_name>
```

and to install packages

```
pip3 install <package_name>
# or 
pip2 install <package_name>
```

This also works for the python version that comes with `Ananconda`.
I hope this is helpful.