# Installing Anaconda on Windows 10: Something went wrong during the installation, and conda cannot be found

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I'm trying to install Anaconda on a Windows 10 laptop at work. For some reason, the installation always fails: I can see the Anaconda prompt, but no trace of Anaconda Navigator, Spyder, etc.
Every time I type `where conda` in the command prompt or the Anaconda prompt I always get the following message:

```
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
```

And every time I try to use a `conda` command, I get:

```
'conda' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I know I messed up something in the installation (that I already tried a couple of times). I always kept the default options as I found in this [DataCamp tutorial](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/installing-anaconda-windows#install) but I don't understand what is my mistake.

Any help? Thank you

Comment: Hard to say if you messed up with the installation. You should try to find where conda is installed and execute the conda binary from there. If that works, you need to add the directory to the PATH environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added conda to your path?

[Conda command is not recognized on Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44597662/conda-command-is-not-recognized-on-windows-10)

Once it is in your path, your OS will be able to know what you mean when you give it the 'conda' command.

```
where conda  # windows
which conda  # linux
```

should show you the path to the executable when you have set it up correctly.

Answer (score 0):

if your installation path is something like: C:\Program Files\Anaconda2 or 3
please change it to: C:\Anaconda
and be sure that the check box in pic blow is checked.
[installation screen picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2gPG.png)