# The 'conda' command is not available

Tags: snakemake

I install snakemake on Windows, using Vagrant, VirtualBox and Ubuntu 18.04.

On the virtual machine, I create a conda environment to run snakemake:

```
conda create --name snake -c bioconda -c conda-forge snakemake-minimal graphviz pandas
# python v3.7.2
# conda v4.5.11
# snakemake v5.3.1
```

(Record of the installation procedure [here](https://github.com/mhebrard/smk-ATAC-seq/wiki/Setup))

From this environment, I can run `conda list` and `conda install` without issue. I can also run `snakemake`.

Problem rise when I try to use `conda` directive in one of my rule

```
rule create_index:
    input: config['fasta']
    output: directory("results/index")
    conda: "envs/smk-bowtie2.yaml"
    shell: "bowtie2-build {input} {output}/hg38"
```

with envs/smk-bowtie2.yaml as follow

```
channels:
    - bioconda
dependencies:
    - bowtie2 =2.3.4.3
```

When I run (on my local machine)

```
snakemake -np --use-conda
```

I get the error

```
Building DAG of jobs...
CreateCondaEnvironmentException:
The 'conda' command is not available.
```

I don't understand what I am missing...

**[EDIT]:** simple test:

```
rule all
    shell: "conda --version
```

commands:

```
conda --version
# prompt
# conda 4.5.11

snakemake
# prompt
# /bin/bash: conda: command not found
```

Comment: It is not a duplicate, as I get the error when running in local (will edit the question)

Comment: Ok, thank you for the clarification.

Comment: What operating system are you using? This might help you on Windows: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44597662/conda-command-is-not-recognized-on-windows-10

Comment: I edit the question with some detail about the installation. I am on windows, but I run snakemake using vagrant to communicate by ssh with a virtual machine Ubuntu 18.04 ... so at the end I am on Linux for runing conda and snakemake... conda list and conda install works fine from the terminal... only problem is "within" snakemake