# Running python scripts from command line using different python versions defined in anaconda envs

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, cmd, anaconda

I have 2 python tools that I have to run via the windows cmd line. One is written in python2.7 while the other requires python3.6.

I have installed the newest Anaconda python3.7 version and created two new environments in 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs' called 'python27' and 'python36'. For some reason I had to manually install numpy and scipy using `conda install -n env_name numpy scipy` for each of the new environments.

The reason I have to run both tools using the windows cmd line is that I have integrated them into a workflow environment (RCE by the DLR in case this is relevant), which executes integrated tools in this way. Which means I cannot simply use the Anaconda Prompt instead.

I cannot simply add the python installation to the PATH environment variable because of each tool requiring a different python version (and the file being called 'python.exe' in all versions), so I tried to create aliases for the cmd prompt as suggested by "roryhewitt" in this thread [Aliases in Windows command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20530996/aliases-in-windows-command-prompt).

my 'python27.bat' file:

```
@echo off
echo.
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\python27\python.exe %*
```

The problem with this approach is that python encounters an error when trying to import numpy:

```
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 71, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError:

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
Here is how to proceed:
- If you're working with a numpy git repository, try `git clean -xdf`
  (removes all files not under version control) and rebuild numpy.
- If you are simply trying to use the numpy version that you have installed:
  your installation is broken - please reinstall numpy.
- If you have already reinstalled and that did not fix the problem, then:
  1. Check that you are using the Python you expect (you're using C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\python27\python.exe),
     and that you have no directories in your PATH or PYTHONPATH that can
     interfere with the Python and numpy versions you're trying to use.
  2. If (1) looks fine, you can open a new issue at
     https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues.  Please include details on:
     - how you installed Python
     - how you installed numpy
     - your operating system
     - whether or not you have multiple versions of Python installed
     - if you built from source, your compiler versions and ideally a build log

     Note: this error has many possible causes, so please don't comment on
     an existing issue about this - open a new one instead.

Original error was: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Does anyone know a better way to run python scripts with a specific python environment via the windows cmd line, or what is causing the import error when I use the alias?

TLDR: I have 2 python tools that require python2.7 and python3.6 respectively. I have to run these tools using the windows cmd line and using aliases to the 'python.exe' file in the specific anaconda environments results in an import error of numpy. Is there a better way to handle two python environments via the cmd line or an easy fix for the import error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the ImportError when using python2.7 via the alias in the cmd line was due to the anaconda environment not being activated. This caused the module to be unable to load properly.

I have added the conda functionality to be used in the cmd line as instructed in the post by "Simba" here: [Conda command is not recognized on Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44597662/conda-command-is-not-recognized-on-windows-10/58211115#58211115). This has fixed the numpy ImportError.

I can now execute the desired tools from the cmd line using the correct python version by activating the correct anaconda environment first, and then calling the alias

Example:

```
C:\Users\user>conda activate python27

(python27) C:\Users\user>python27 main.py
```