# Updated Anaconda but it broke, so uninstalled and installed again but it is not working?

Tags: python, spyder, anaconda3

Yesterday I updated anaconda and spyder and today I could not open anything. So i unistalled and installed again. Now I can see the app in the app menu on start but it does not open. I have tried in the command terminal as well but it is not opening. Can anyone help?

Before reinstalling the prompt was working but now neither the prompt or the navigator are working.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling anaconda is risky. You should follow the official guide :

https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/uninstall/

I recommend you to use **anaconda clean** then remove again at option B.

```
conda install anaconda-clean

anaconda-clean --yes
```

And before reinstall it, be sure you can completely clean it.

Comment: Thanks but I can't open the navigator or prompt so where to write those commands?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58211115/3756587 there is a possibility that you can use it from windows cmd. can u pls try it.