# How to use conda within a virtual environment?

Tags: python, anaconda

I am on windows. I made a venv using `virtualenv`

```
python -m venv venv2
```

And installed packages with `pip install NAME`.

Now I am trying to install [OSMnx](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) package, but that requires conda. I have already installed anaconda for the system as a whole and added it to PATH.

However I am not sure how I can use it in the virtual environment.

Running command like

```
conda config --prepend channels conda-forge
```

yields the error

```
conda : The term 'conda' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is
```

correct and try again.

So how can I install this conda package in virtual environment?

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44597662/conda-command-is-not-recognized-on-windows-10/58211115 to use conda in your cli or use the "Anaconda Prompt" windows cli like tool for windows, which should also be installed on your system

Comment: @Pierre  conda in cli works elsewhere but for some reason not in the virtual environment

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why, but the issue resolved itself. Using `conda` command works in virtualenv as expected.