# After installing anaconda, my laptop acts as though it doesn't exist

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, command-prompt, anaconda3

**WARNING: This whole thing could just be me being an idiot since I am a 10-year old**

I installed Anaconda on my Windows 10 to use Jupyter, but when I want to use the `jupyter notebook` commands at all, it gives this message:
`'jupyter' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Not only that but when I try to use any 'conda' commands, I get a similar error message.
I've reinstalled the application several times, just in case something went wrong in the downloading process. I've also tried to change the directory, but nothing seems to solve the problem

Is there a solution available?

Thanks,
Siddhu

Comment: can you check please if conda is in your PATH?

type ```echo $PATH``` in your shell and check if there is something with conda like ```/home/yourname/anaconda/bin/python```

Comment: thanks - I tried it and it wasn't there

Comment: Then add it :) This may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44597662/conda-command-is-not-recognized-on-windows-10