# conda command not found in cmd after correctly installed anaconda

Tags: python

I have anaconda installed on my PC, win 10 OS. In cmd, when typed in conda command, it reports conda is not recognized as a command.
If I pip install conda, there would be error in red. What would be the possible reasons? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

One of the possible reasons is that you didn't add the conda executable path to your environmental variables path variable.

Which I think is the reason for your problem here because you have already installed anaconda.

See this ([Conda command is not recognized on Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44597662/conda-command-is-not-recognized-on-windows-10)).

It have the same problem with answers.