# conda commands not returning anything

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, environment

I am a beginner with python. I just installed anaconda distribution for windows, opened the anaconda command promt and entered the line `conda --version` but it returned error saying conda is not recognized. So I followed the steps in this [thread](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibppc.jpg) which solved the error. However, now running conda commands are not returning anything as you can see [image: here].

I have also changed the path in environment variables in the system settings.[image: here]

Comment: @topsail I tried that too but there is no response.

Comment: The link you provided in "This Thread" is not working.

Comment: These instructions looks like the correct ones: [conda-command-is-not-recognized-on-windows-10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44597662/conda-command-is-not-recognized-on-windows-10) The answer that says "Things have been changed after conda 4.6." It makes no sense that the anaconda prompt doesn't work though - that requires no fiddling or special steps. Maybe undo the changes you made to PATH and reinstall anaconda. You can init your shell instead, which is the way recommended by anaconda.