# I can't run python script in visual studio code

Tags: python

I have problem in running python script in visual studio code, in other IDE I dont have issue I run the same python script without any issue.

in the terminal I got this message
conda activate base
conda : The term 'conda' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of
the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- conda activate base
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (conda:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

Comment: Just a few questions: What other IDE were you using? What operating system are you using? There may be a path issue https://stackoverflow.com/q/44597662/8678978

Comment: I used spyder (anaconda3) and I use windows 10

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like there is an issue with the interpreter.

1. Open the Command Palette in Visual Studio Code by pressing Ctrl + Shift + P
2. Type "Python: Select Interpreter" and select it.
3. Choose the conda environment that you want to use from the list of available interpreters.
4. After selecting the interpreter, close and reopen VSC (for changes to take effect).

Once you have the correct interpreter, you should be able to run the script in the terminal.