# keras backend theano/tensorflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I have an issue using keras backend. I set up tensorflow as the backend. I check the ./keras/keras.json, the activate.d and activate.sh to have tensorflow as backend. I also tried to force the envs variable to tensorflow.
The first time a run keras on the jupyter, it works fine. I can also import tensorflow without any bugs.

However when I use jupyter notebook now, the backend is theano.

I try to import keras on ipython and the backend is tensorflow.

I install keras, tensorflow and theano with conda.

python version : 3.6

keras : 2.0.6

tensorflow : 1.3.0

theano : 0.9

OS : win10

I try different ways to change the backend to tensorflow for jupyter notebook but it does not seem to work.

Comment: I faced a terrible bug with jupyter. I installed it before installing anaconda, and no matter what I did, jupyter was always pointing to the original python and never to the conda environments. In my case (A virtual machine), I gave up and created a new machine, installing jupyter only via conda and at the right environment.

Comment: @DanielMöller, I actually installed jupyter with conda. I am now using ipython and will try to create a specific environment, as you mentioned.

Comment: One possible way to kwnow which python you're using from jypiter is running `import sys` and `print(sys.executable)`. This will tell you if jupyter is running the correct environment.

Comment: Thank you for your help @DanielMöller! It points to Anaconda3/python.exe, which is the correct one. I change the __init__.py in Anaconda3/lib/site-packages/keras/backend , in the import backend functions  line 80, I replace `from .theano_backend import *` to `from .tensorflow_backend import *`. It seems to do the trick.

Comment: Nice hack :) -- Jupyter should be running somewhere in a folder called `envs\yourenvironment` for it to work properly without your hack.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, with conda, we create specific environments that are (theoretically) independent from the others.

I suggest you create a tensorflow environment using conda. Using the command prompt:

```
conda create -n myTensorflowEnv python=3.5
```

And then you activate this environment:

```
activate myTensorflowEnv
```

The name of your environment should then appear in between parentheses at the beginning of the command prompt. (In case this doesn't work, you may need to setup some vars: [How to activate an Anaconda environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20081338/how-to-activate-an-anaconda-environment))

Inside this environment, you install everything you need: Tensorflow, keras and other dependencies. This process will depend on what you want, though, cpu, gpu, compilations, etc.

You should probably install jupyter in this environment as well. (And perhaps -- only if you have the terrible bug I mentioned in my comment -- uninstall the other jupyters first).

If everything goes well, you will be able to use tensorflow in this environment if you run jupyter from this environment.