# Importerror: cannot import name logging

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging, psychopy

I am using Psychopy 1.83.03, 32 bit and python anaconda 2.7 64 bit on windows 10 64 bit.

When I am trying to import core, data, event, gui, and visual, it gives me an import error. Below is the code and the error traceback.

```
from __future__ import division, print_function
from win32api import GetSystemMetrics
import numpy as np
import os

from psychopy import core, data, event, gui, visual 
import qmix
import cv2
import threading
#import time
import datetime
#from timeit import default_timer as timer
#import xlwt
#import xlsxwriter
#import openpyxl
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-37-f571478c27e1>", line 20, in <module>
from psychopy import core, data, event, gui, visual

File "C:\Users\ravikumar.mevada\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\psychopy\event.py", line 57, in <module>
from psychopy import logging

ImportError: cannot import name logging
```

Comment: try activating your anaconda environment and run again [try this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20081338/how-to-activate-an-anaconda-environment)

Comment: @whoami I have tried but there is no difference.

Comment: try pip install

Comment: @whoami I have tried pip install logging but there is no difference.

Comment: are you using linux

Comment: if linux what does `which pip` and  `which python` give

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will install it in its own Python version folder:

```
python3.6 -m pip install pakage-name
```