# I am trying to add a python interpreter as a Virtualenv Environment at Pycharm using an Anaconda environment

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda

This shows my Anaconda Environment. I created a new environment named "my_env."

[image]

However, when I tried to add a Python Interpreter from an existing environment and tried to select my_env from the "envs" folder, there was none.

[image]

Can anyone please let me know how I can navigate my "my_env" environment from the second screenshot?

Thanks.

Comment: Select "New Environment" radio button, add your virtualenv path up to where python.exe resides

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20081338/how-to-activate-an-anaconda-environment) answer might help.

You need to add the anaconda envs folder to the path, for example:

`set PATH=C:\Anaconda\envs\py3x\Scripts;C:\Anaconda\envs\py3x;%PATH%`

and once that's done you can activate the environment by using the command:

`activate my_env`

in the pycharm terminal, and it should activate and show by prefixing the terminal with:

`(my_env)`

Comment: Where can I set the PATH as shown in your answer? Should I set it at Anaconda's terminal?

Comment: I think if you have conda installed on the path, you can try and use ```activate my_env``` in the terminal.