# Install local package in anaconda environment

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

**ISSUE:** I would like to install local package in a specific conda environment. To do that, I read the current documentation ([python-packaging](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)).

**package structure:**

```
$ pwd
~/…/test
.
|- requirements.txt
|- my_package
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- base.py
|- setup.py
```

**setup.py**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
from setuptools import setup

with open('requirements.txt') as f:
    requirements = f.read().splitlines()

setup(
    name='my_package',
    version='2.0.0',
    author='B.Gees',
    author_email='B.Gees@gmail.com',
    license='MIT',
    packages=['my_package'],
    description='my package description',
    long_description='my package long description',
    keywords='chemistry machine learning cheminformatics',
    classifiers=[
        'Environment :: Console',
        'Intended Audience :: Developers',
        'Intended Audience :: Healthcare Industry',
        'Intended Audience :: Science/Research',
        'License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License',
        'Operating System :: OS Independent',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.5',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.5.5',
        'Topic :: Scientific/Engineering',
        'Topic :: Scientific/Engineering :: Bio-Informatics',
        'Topic :: Scientific/Engineering :: Chemistry',
        'Topic :: Scientific/Engineering :: Pharmacokinetic',
        'Topic :: Software Development :: Libraries :: Python Modules',
    ],
    install_requires=requirements,
    zip_safe=False
)
```

**requirements.txt**

```
pandas==0.19.2
dill==0.2.7.1
cython==0.23.4
```

**__init__.py**

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

"""
my_package
~~~~~~~~~~

my package full description

:copyright: (c) 2018 by B.Gees.
:license: MIT, see LICENSE file for more details.
"""

from __future__ import print_function
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from __future__ import division
import logging

__title__ = 'my_package'
__version__ = '2.0.0'
__author__ = 'B.Gees'
__email__ = 'B.Gees@gmail.com'
__license__ = 'MIT'
__copyright__ = 'Copyright 2018 B.Gees'

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
log.addHandler(logging.NullHandler())
```

**base.py**

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

def titi(x):
    return x**2
```

I install my package in a specific conda environment with the folowing code lines:

```
conda activate my_env
pip install . # In my package repository
```

Nevertheless, when I try to import `my_package` in jupyter notebook, I obtain the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-daa52839320b> in <module>()
----> 1 import my_package

ImportError: No module named 'my_package'
```

This installation works fine when I used python `pip` outer conda environment.

**QUESTION:** I don't know how to install my package correctly in a specific conda environment. I need your lights to enlighten me.

*CONFIGURATION: MacOSX with conda3 and python3.5 ; Need to be compatible with Linux 7*

Comment: did you tried to use conda install my_package ? you can also use conda search my_package in your env to check if the package is well installed

Comment: Doesn't work for me :/

Comment: what is the output of conda search my_package

Comment: `PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:Current channels: - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-64` It dosn't take into account my local environment

Comment: So the package is not installed in your env, try to use pip install my_package, until using pip install .

Comment: `pip install my_package` and `pip install .` give the same output : `Successfully installed my_package`. In jupyter notebook I have the same `ImportError`

Comment: You can also link the folder in the development mode with anaconda `conda develop <directory>` -  https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/resources/commands/conda-develop.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using MacOSX, so you should firstly use `source activate yourenvname`, then you can use what you did to install your package. for more information [How to activate an Anaconda environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20081338/how-to-activate-an-anaconda-environment)

so start with : `conda create --name my_env python=3.5`
then `source activate my_env`

Comment: I already activate my environment before install local package. This doesn't fix my issue :/.

Comment: did you tried to just import your package in the terminal; run python and then import my_package?without using jupiter

Comment: Yes, but this is the same problem

Comment: try to use : `/anaconda/envs/my_env/bin/pip install my_package` works only if you have `my_env` in `/anaconda/envs/`. I suggest you to use also `conda install pip` before doing that

Comment: I have tried these solutions. I realize that the explanation of my problem is not clear and I apologize for that. I'm preparing an update to explain you all the things I've tested.

Comment: @B.Gees if you succeed to install your package in your local machine, the problem is then due to your configuration of anaconda. waiting for your edit :)

Comment: when I recreate a new environment, I no longer have a problem. I have only updated my pip `You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 18.1 is available` and it works. It's surprising. I can still offer you my update to see if the process is correct?

Comment: I used the folowing command lines: `conda create --name my_package python=3.5 --no-default-packages` ; ` source activate my_package` ; `conda install jupyter` ; `conda install pip` ; `pip install --upgrade pip` ; `pip install .` and my_package is available in my conda environement. Thanks a lot C.med for your attention