# python in conda environment, but cannot activate

Tags: python, anaconda

I have installed anaconda and create and activated an environment with anaconda prompt.
But when I open python with anaconda, whether inside my anaconda folder or inside the environment folder in it, (or even if I open a python file with spider), it seems it is not using anaconda (according to sys.version).
Indeed python tells me "this python is in a conda environment, but the environment has not been activated". 
I have already activated my environment in conda prompt, and I had no error message, so I guess it was succesfful. I have also tried to set my path with in conda prompt: set PATH=C:\Anaconda\envs\py33\Scripts;C:\Anaconda\envs\py33;%PATH% (with my right personal path).

Would you know what is happening?

Thank you
[picture of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUwbz.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to activate an Anaconda environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20081338/how-to-activate-an-anaconda-environment)

Comment: Activation should happen in your command prompt window not in python, 'conda activate' is not a pyhton command.

Comment: thank you, but i had already tried to write conda activate in my anaconda prompt. it successfully changes from (base) to (name of my created environment) . but it doesn't solve my problem: nothing changes when I use python (sys.version still indicates python without specifying anaconda)

Comment: Your assumption that creating a new environment will give you a Python that has "Anaconda" in the `sys.version` string is incorrect. Please use `sys.prefix` to identify where the binary is located instead.

Comment: thank you. when is write sys.prefix, then python gives me C:\\Users\\myusername\\Anaconda3\\envs\\myenv' . So indeed there is anaconda. But still, python says when opening: "this python interpreter is in a conda environment, but the environment has not been activated". Althought I did activated in conda prompt..
Should I add path variables inside windows manually? In this case, what would be the variable name and the variable value?