# Anaconda 4.7.12 activate environment not work

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, conda

I create an environment using this command:

```
conda create -n my_env11 python=3.7.3
```

but when I use the following command:

```
conda activate my_env11
```

doesn't work

note:
anaconda version is
4.7.12

Comment: Could you please expand? For example, include how you know this (e.g., did you run `which python`), maybe add `conda info` and/or `conda env list` and/or `conda list -n my_env11` outputs.

Comment: In which way does the activate command not work? Is there an error message?

Comment: I find the solution in this link [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20081338/how-to-activate-an-anaconda-environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20081338/how-to-activate-an-anaconda-environment) thanks