# How do I see which versions of packages are compatible with one another

Tags: pandas, conda, bioconductor

I am trying to download Pandas less than 2.0.0 and simultaneously load bioconductor deseq2. Unfortunately, they don't seem to resolve with one another.

```
(base) [mfaleeva@papr-res-compute02 ARTDeco]$ conda create -n art_panda_deseq 'bioconductor-deseq2>=1.20' 'pandas>=0.24.2,<2.0.0'
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: unsuccessful attempt using repodata from current_repodata.json, retrying with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): \ Bus error
```

I was wondering whether there is a way to check which versions of packages are compatible with each other/ up to which version where they compatible.
Many thanks!

Comment: Should try to use poetry It will make your life so much easier

Comment: Attempting to access memory that doesn't exist? bus error doesn't look like your typical faulty install bug. Bu:t https://stackoverflow.com/q/61134985/12846804 points to a bad `.condarc` file. Helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/q/212466/12846804