# cannot create a virtual environment

Tags: anaconda, virtualenv, conda, python-venv, virtual-environment

I've recently changed my OS to windows 10 and setup anaconda 3. The problem is that in Anaconda Navigator (in the Environment tab) when clicking on the create button to make a new virtual environment, after setting a name and the python version (to 3.7 as the only option), the venv won't be created, instead, I get this error:

```
CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win- 
64/current_repodata.json><br>Elapsed: -<br><br>An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this 
URL.<br>HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.<br><br>If 
your current network has https://www.anaconda.com blocked, please file<br>a support request with your 
network engineering team.<br><br>'https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64'<br>
```

Although I can open this file in my browser: https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win- 64/current_repodata.json

On the other hand, when I try to make a virtual env following these steps:

```
mkdir projects
cd projects
mkdir drdr
cd drdr
python -m venv ./venv
```

Then when I activate the venv like below:

```
venv\Scripts\activate.bat
```

I get:

```
(venv) (base) C:\Users\shima\projects\drdr>
```

which I don't know what is (venv) (base). Should I realize it activated or not. Even when I try to activate my venv by the code below:

```
conda activate venv
```

I get this message:

```
Could not find conda environment: venv
```

Also, after making the venv, when I want to import it in my navigator no matter I choose which folder inside my venv folder, I can't import it

By the way, checking whether firewall allows traffic from anaconda, I cannot find anaconda in the list of allowed apps and trying to add it the list, I don't know what folder inside anaconda's folder I should add

I don't know why this problem has happened, and couldn't find an answer in anaconda documents or others questions here in StackOverflow, so I really appreciate any help in this issue.

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: ```(venv)``` indicates that you're already in the virtualenv.

Comment: @ewong don't you have any idea how I can fix this, even reinstalling didn't help

Comment: might this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20081338/how-to-activate-an-anaconda-environment

Comment: setting the PATH, the same error happens: Could not find conda environment: venv

Comment: Even trying to create the venv the way it is mentioned in that post, I get the same error: CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for URL ....

Comment: you're supposed to create the environment with conda before activating it.

Comment: I've created a venv inside the folder I want using this command: python -m venv ./venv

Comment: But I can't activate it. On the other hand, using another command line, mentioned in the post you sent for me, I couldn't even make a venv, forget about activating it @ewong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
python -m venv ./venv
```

you are mixng `conda` virtual environments with `virtualenv` virtual environments, hence all the confusion:

```
(venv) (base) C:\Users\shima\projects\drdr>
```

does look strange, because it is. You are in the `base`environment of conda, but have activated a virtualenv environment called `venv`

> Could not find conda environment: venv

there is no conda enviroment `venv`, you have never created one.

**In short:**

When using conda, don't use virtualenv, insted use

```
 conda create -n venv
```

to create a virtual environment and

```
conda activate venv
```

to activate it

Comment: Thank you @FlyingTeller, I used your command line, I got this error:

Comment: (base) C:\Users\shima\projects\drdr>conda create -n venv
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/current_repodata.json>
Elapsed: -

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.

If your current network has https://www.anaconda.com blocked, please file
a support request with your network engineering team.

'https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64'