# Is there an "activate" script in an Anaconda environment?

Tags: python, anaconda, virtualenv, conda

For activating a virtual environment (virtualenv) I usually source the file *venv_name/bin/activate* (or *venv_name\Scripts\activate* in Windows).

Does an Anaconda environment (located in the folder *Anaconda3/envs*) has this "*activate*" script? And if so, where is it located?

Comment: This should be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20081338/how-to-activate-an-anaconda-environment

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bconda%5D+activate