# using python.exe of the anaconda with external scripts

Tags: python, command, line, environment

when I try to use python.exe in the anaconda3 file, the python command line shows up. I can use the cmd file with conda activation, but it does not work for external python scripts and task scheduling.

```
This Python interpreter is in a conda environment, but the environment has not been activated.  Libraries may fail to load.  To activate this environment please see https://conda.io/activation
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to activate an Anaconda environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20081338/how-to-activate-an-anaconda-environment)

Comment: please check https://conda.io/activation on how to activate an anaconda environment