# What 's the difference between executing conda-unpack and not when transfering environments through conda-pack

Tags: conda, conda-pack

From docs of conda-pack: https://conda.github.io/conda-pack/

## Questions about code comments below:

**Q1:**What do "Cleanup prefixes" and "active environment" mean?

**Q2:**What 's the difference between executing conda-unpack and not

```
# Cleanup prefixes from in the active environment.
# Note that this command can also be run without activating the environment
# as long as some version of python is already installed on the machine.
(my_env) $ conda-unpack
```

source url:
[https://conda.github.io/conda-pack/#:~:text=%23%20Cleanup%20prefixes%20from%20in%20the%20active%20environment.%0A%23%20Note%20that%20this%20command%20can%20also%20be%20run%20without%20activating%20the%20environment%0A%23%20as%20long%20as%20some%20version%20of%20python%20is%20already%20installed%20on%20the%20machine.%0A(my_env)%20%24%20conda%2Dunpack](https://conda.github.io/conda-pack/#:%7E:text=%23%20Cleanup%20prefixes%20from%20in%20the%20active%20environment.%0A%23%20Note%20that%20this%20command%20can%20also%20be%20run%20without%20activating%20the%20environment%0A%23%20as%20long%20as%20some%20version%20of%20python%20is%20already%20installed%20on%20the%20machine.%0A(my_env)%20%24%20conda%2Dunpack)

I execute as the docs says all the cmds except for the "conda-unpack", because I'm not aware of the influence on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## active environment

The `active environment` refers to the currently activated conda environment. This is what you do when using `conda activate`, which activates the standard conda environment, or `conda activate envname`with `envname` being a specific named environment.

When you activate an environment, you are telling your system to use the specific versions of packages and dependencies installed in that environment.

More on that see
[How to activate an Anaconda environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20081338/how-to-activate-an-anaconda-environment)

## cleanup prefixes

`Cleanup prefixes` refers to the process of removing any hard-coded paths in the environment's files that point to the location of the environment on the source machine. This is necessary when moving a conda environment to a new machine or location.

## conda unpack

`conda-unpack` is a command that should be run after unpacking a conda environment on a new machine or location. It performs the cleanup of prefixes and sets up scripts for activating and deactivating the environment. If you don't run conda-unpack, you may encounter issues with hard-coded paths in the environment's files.