# R Markdown: Can't access Bash command installed through Conda/Anaconda

Tags: r, bash, r-markdown, conda, environment

I'm exploring some bioinformatics data and I like to use R notebooks (i.e. Rmarkdown) when I can. Right now, I need to use a command line tool to analyze a VCF file and I would like to do it through a Bash code chunk in the Rmarkdown notebook.

The problem is that the command I want to use was installed with `conda` into my conda environment. The tool is `bcftools`. When I try to access this command, I get this error (code chunk commented out to show rmarkdown code chunk format):

````
#```{bash}
bcftools view -H test.vcf.gz
#```
````

```
/var/folders/9l/phf62p1s0cxgnzp4hgl7hy8h0000gn/T/RtmplzEvEh/chunk-code-6869322acde0.txt: line 3: bcftools: command not found
```

Whereas if I run from Terminal, I get output (using conda environment called "binfo"):

```
> bcftools view -H test.vcf.gz | head -n 3
chr10   78484538    .   A   C   .   PASS    DP=57;SOMATIC;SS=2;SSC=16;GPV=1;SPV=0.024109    GT:GQ:DP:RD:AD:FREQ:DP4 0/0:.:34:33:0:0%:0,33,0,0   0/1:.:23:19:4:17.39%:1,18,0,4
chr12   4333138 .   G   T   .   PASS    DP=119;SOMATIC;SS=2;SSC=14;GPV=1;SPV=0.034921   GT:GQ:DP:RD:AD:FREQ:DP4 0/0:.:72:71:1:1.39%:71,0,1,0    0/1:.:47:42:5:10.64%:42,0,5,0
chr15   75086860    .   C   T   .   PASS    DP=28;SOMATIC;SS=2;SSC=18;GPV=1;SPV=0.013095    GT:GQ:DP:RD:AD:FREQ:DP4 0/0:.:15:15:0:0%:4,11,0,0   0/1:.:13:8:5:38.46%:5,3,1,4
(binfo)
```

So, how do I access tools installed with conda/in my conda env from an R notebook/Rmarkdown bash code chunk? I searched for quite a while and could not find anyone talking about running `conda` commands in a shell chunk in Rmarkdown. Any help would be appreciated because I like the R notebook format for exploratory analysis.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Passing Arguments to Engines

If your Conda is [properly configured to work in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55526573/570918), then you can use `engine.opts` to tell bash to launch in login mode (i.e., source your `.bash_profile` (Mac) or `.bashrc` (Linux)):

#### bash

````bash
```{bash engine.opts='-l'}
bcftools view -H test.vcf.gz
```
````

#### zsh

If working with `zsh` (e.g., Mac OS 10.15 Catalina users), then the interactive flag, `--interactive|-i` is what you want (Credit: **@Leo**).

````
```{zsh engine.opts='-i'}
bcftools view -H test.vcf.gz
```
````

Again, this presumes you've previously run `conda init zsh` to set up Conda to work with the shell.

## Note on Reproducibility

Since reproducibility is usually a concern in scientific work, I will add that you may want to do something to capture the state of your Conda environment. For example, if you are working in version control, then commit a `conda env export > environment.yaml`. Another option would be to output that info directly at the end of the Rmd, like what is usually done with `sessionInfo()`.  That is,

````bash
```{bash engine.opts='-l', comment=NA}
conda env export
```
````

where the `comment=NA` is so that the output can be cleanly copied from the rendered version.

Comment: I actually could not get this to work with `zsh`. My chunk header is: `{zsh, engine.opts='-l'}`. I get the same error I was running into originally: `/var/folders/dr/tx09yq8n7s9b2mnlyh5lhxvr0000gn/T/RtmpxVYtGE/chunk-code-c6e560c02889.txt:2: command not found: bcftools`. The only way I've figure out how to use zsh is to add a `source ~/.zshrc` line at the start of the chunk so it can find the `bcftools` binary in `/Users/<USERNAME>/anaconda3/bin/bcftools`. Is there an equivalent way for zsh to auto source `~/.zshrc` like Bash does `~/.bash_profile` with `'-l'`?

Comment: I got it to work by switching the engine options from login (`{zsh, engine.opts='-l'}`) to interactive (`{zsh, engine.opts='-i'}`). Likely due to the differences in how Zsh sources dotfiles compared to Bash.

Comment: @Leo thanks for the note. I updated the answer with that info.

Answer (score 0):

Quick solution for `bash`: **prepend** the following init script into your Bash scripts.

```sh
eval "$(command conda 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"

# you may need to activate the "base" environment explicitly
conda activate base
```

#### Detail

When you open your terminal, an interactive shell is spawned. But your script is run in a non-interactive shell. Bash configuration file `~/.bashrc` will not be used for the scripts, which skips the `conda` initialization and your "base" environment is not exposed into `PATH`.

#### References

- [Python - Activate conda env through shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58081608/5101148)

Comment: I tried this but I'm still getting an error when even trying to access the `conda activate` command to activate my env: `# Test Bash chunk ```{bash} eval "$(command conda 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)" conda activate binfo bcftools
``` /var/folders/9l/phf62p1s0cxgnzp4hgl7hy8h0000gn/T/Rtmpcy5EuN/chunk-code-80345e779e.txt: line 2: conda: command not found
/var/folders/9l/phf62p1s0cxgnzp4hgl7hy8h0000gn/T/Rtmpcy5EuN/chunk-code-80345e779e.txt: line 3: bcftools: command not found `