# How to run a python script (with args) in Rmarkdown

Tags: python, bash, r-markdown

I am trying to execute a python script inside an rmarkdown document using bash. This is the code:

```sh
python 'path_to_file\file_to_execute.py' --net linear_nn --hid 10
```

The file requires both `--net` and `--hid` arguments to be specified.

When I execute the cell individually in RStudio I can see that it turns the expected output. However, when I go to knit the document (with the above chunk included) I get an error message as follows:

> Error in engine(options) : /bin/bash: python: command not found Calls:
>  ... process_group.block -> call_block -> block_exec ->
> in_dir -> engine In addition: Warning message: In system2(cmd, code,
> stdout = TRUE, stderr = TRUE, env = options$engine.env) :   running
> command '"bash"  -c "python 'path_to_file\file_to_execute.py'
> --net polar --hid 10 "' had status 127 Execution halted

I have tried the approach of using `bash` but perhaps that was not the right way to execute python files with arguments in rMarkdown. Would anyone know how to solve this problem so that I can knit the whole document without issue?

Comment: What happens if you specify an absolute path to a Python binary in your Rmd? eg. `/usr/bin/python 'path_to_file\file_to_execute.py' --net linear_nn --hid 10`

Comment: Rather than using an absolute path to a Python binary, another option may be to specify `engine.opts='-l'` in your bash chunk code options. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58138894/11021886 for more details

Comment: Same outcome in both cases I'm afraid @jwalton