# use an install.sh in a specific conda env

Tags: linux, anaconda3

I have downloaded some [software](https://github.com/marbl/MetaCarvel) from github. for installation it provides an install.sh with the following commands

```
#!/bin/bash
#install OGDF
cd OGDF
./makeMakefile.py
make -j 16
cd ..

#install METACARVEL
make
```

I want to make sure it gets installed in an specific conda env because I have all the dependencies installed there.
Is this possible? Can you guide me on how to do it?

thanks all :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - Activate conda env through shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55507519/python-activate-conda-env-through-shell-script)

Comment: Thanks, but not really. I found that the installation directory is not much of a problem as long as I have the environment activated while using the program.