# How to install Geopandas for Mac and Python 3.8? Conda install Geopandas doesn't work

Tags: python, conda, spyder, geopandas

I want to install Geopandas in Mac. First I tried to install with: conda install geopandas, this was the result:

[image: After two minutes the execution never ends]

After that, I look in other websites what might happen, so I found this link:

https://justinhchae.medium.com/install-geopandas-with-conda-and-pycharm-on-macos-5d1f0d092052

Which says that It's normal that happen this kind of problem depending on the environment, so I did what it's said:

[image: Second way of install Geopandas with creating new enviroment]

I could create the new environment gis_project properly. After that, I ran the second line, which is for activating the new environment, but I had this problem which I haven't achieved to work yet.

[image: Activate environment error]

Then I tried conda init with every shell, but nothing happen just this:

[image: conda init zsh]

I've also tried with bash, because I'm using Mac, but still problems with a password that I don't know how to write because it seems stuck

[image: conda init bash]

I don't know if you had the same problems, but it's been a strong headache for me to install Geopandas in Mac,
Would you mind helping me with this?

Comment: Please include [formatted code blocks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) rather than links. See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: One option - try [`mamba`](https://mamba.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) - it's a compiled (mostly) clone of conda which is much faster. But it sounds like there may be other things going on with the way you're using conda environments. Please post your code in your question so we can help (without following a bunch of links). Thanks!

Comment: Please paste your code as formatted code blocks, not links/pictures, and please edit your question to provide more content - don't answer your question with comments. It looks like you have something in your shell setup (e.g. in `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile`?) which is requiring a password and is preventing conda from activating. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55507519/python-activate-conda-env-through-shell-script.

Comment: What shell is actually being used? Are you running in some IDE? - that doesn't look MacOS Terminal. Overall, this question needs focus: the geopandas part is completely solved in the post (remove it - it is irrelevant) and the question is essentially about how to activate a Conda environment from whatever shell is being used. Most likely the shell isn't loading the relevant resources file (need to enable login mode).

Comment: @merv Thanks for your answer. Yes, I'm using Sypder to activate the environment. How can I solve the problem to enable this new environment? Is it necessary to do it through the MacOS Terminal?  I don't see any other solution. Just to give up and try to use another library instead of Geopandas.

Comment: Apologies for delayed response. If you wish to use Spyder, then I suggest reading [the documentation on using Conda environments with Spyder](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/wiki/Working-with-packages-and-environments-in-Spyder). From what I understand, their recommendation is to use environments as kernels, and that isn't something one can switch in the Spyder terminal on-the-fly.